# Image zooming using jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

M trying to apply `jquery.elevatezoom.js` plugin.

M trying to implement simple zooming image by just calling a method. Problem is, when i hover the cursor on the image, the image is not appearing at the top. although i have used z-index css style for that div.

[image]

Hope someone can understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to give

`position:relative` or `position:absolute`

to the the div and then apply `z-index`, give it a higher value